# Autocorrelation function of wide stationary process

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

Assume $ \left\{ X\left(t\right)\right\} _{t\in\mathbb{R}} $ is a weak stationary process. Meaning :

$ \mathbb{E}\left[X\left(t\right)\right] $ is a constant for any $t\in \mathbb{R}$

The autocorrelation function only depends on time difference:

$ R_{X}\left(t+\tau,t\right)=\mathbb{E}\left[X\left(t+\tau\right)X\left(t\right)\right]:=R_{X}\left(\tau\right) $

And the variacnce is finite for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$:

$ \mathbb{E}\left[X\left(t\right)^{2}\right]=R_{X}\left(0\right)<\infty $

Now, assume there exists $T>0 $ such that $ R_{X}\left(0\right)=R_{X}\left(T\right) $.

How can I prove that the autocorrelation function is periodic with period $ T $? i.e that for any $t\in \mathbb{R} $ the following holds:

$ R_{X}\left(t\right)=R_{X}\left(t+T\right)  $

Thanks in advnace.

Comment: Let $Y(t) = X(t+T) - X(t)$. What's the variance of $Y(t)$ ?

Comment: @OnurOktay Amazing. Thanks!